# Retrieving all of the most recently failed builds from TeamCity via REST

Tags: rest, teamcity

Basically, I would like details of all of the builds where:

- it is the latest build
- is has failed

I'm using TC 8.1, and looking at the API, you'd think that it would be as simple as:

```
guestAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=status:failure
```

but this seems to give you a list of *any* build that has *ever* failed. So if you have a configuration that failed 10 times last year, but hasn't failed since, you'll get the details of all 10 build instances that failed.

Even if I could just get the details of the latest build for each configuration, that would be a great start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so a possibly experimental, undocumented, but functional (at least for now) example:

```
app/rest/buildTypes?locator=paused:false&fields=buildType(id,name,projectId,builds($locator(status:failure,running:false,canceled:false,count:1),build(id,number,status,statusText)))
```

Comment: How on earth did you figure this out?

Comment: I vaguely recall finding an example on a forum post that didn't _quite_ do the same thing and then used trial and error.